# What's wrong with the ?? operator used like this:

Tags: c#, coalesce

So insteed of writing:

```
if (obj.Collection == null)
    obj.Collection = new Collection();
obj.Collection.Add(something);
```

I thought of writing:

```
obj.Collection = obj.Collection ?? new Collection;
obj.Collection.Add(something);
```

It kind of feels wrong, especially this part "obj.Collection = obj.Collection..."

What do you guys think ?

Regards,

Comment: Why does it feels wrong?

Comment: What's the problem? Do you have a problem with `x = x + 1;`?

Comment: Instinctively it feels wrong to me too. But considering David's comment it's probably fine, and the instinct wrong. Now we just need to add the `??=` operator to C# so we can do `obj.Collection ??= new Collection();`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I had to choose between these two blocks of code, I would use the former. It's more readable and it's a common pattern. `??` is useful in scenarios where you need to default a value (e.g., `DateTime date = nullableDateTimeInstance ?? defaultDate;`).

But frankly, I'd try to not end up in situation where I want to add to collection and it's possible that the collection is null. Instead, I'd make sure that the collection is initialized in the constructor or whatever the case may be.

Comment: Or even do the initialization in the getter of property!

Comment: You are very right, but if Collection is a virtual member in a class (let's say a nhibernate entity class). Then you will end up with a warning "Virtual member call in constructor". I prefer the above then this warning.

Comment: @Calin: Please give a very simple block of code that reproduces the warning you are describing because I think done properly that should not be the case.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean:

```
if (obj.Collection == null)
   {
      obj.Collection = new Collection();
   }
obj.Collection.Add(something);
```

If so, you can rewrite it as

```
(obj.Collection = (obj.Collection ?? new Collection())).Add(something);
```

Comment: `(obj.Collection ?? (obj.Collection =  new Collection())).Add(something);` will work however.

Comment: Yeah I realized that shortly after posting the answer and corrected it.

Comment: Practice some more  :)  I can see a compiler error about a mile away by now :p

Comment: That's a nightmare to maintain

Comment: @leppie, your solution will not work if obj.Collection is a read-only property

Comment: spoke too soon, and so will mine :P

Comment: @tenor: I am not changing the rules :)  So according to the OP's code it is not read-only.

Comment: @leppie, you say there's still something wrong with the code. I can't see where. Can you point it out?

Comment: Oh wait, I see you have braces around the assignment. Sorry, my bad :) Mine does avoid reassignment however.

Answer (score 0):

The code will emit an unnecessary assignment (of obj.Collection to itself) if obj.Collection is not null, but other than that it is equivalent to the original.

Looks fine to me provided you don't use it in time critical sections.  Anyway it's possible the compiler can optimise the assignment away, but I don't know if it would or not.

Perhaps it just feels wrong because the original code is such a common and simple pattern that it feels wrong to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it also depends on what the setter of the `Collection` property does. Consider this:

```
public Collection Collection
{
    get { return _collection; }
    set
    {
        _collection = value;
        Thread.Sleep( 1000 ); // or some expensive real work
    }
}
```

In this case, the assignment `obj.Collection = obj.Collection ?? new Collection()` would be really costly.

However, if you need to create a collection "on demand", it's common to use a similar pattern in the property getter, like this:

```
public Collection Collection
{
    get { return _collection ?? ( _collection = new Collection() ); } 
}
```